# Using VBA commands inside an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, excel

can you, as a method to select a cell in an excel formula put in VBA commands?

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(**Range(NamedRange).Cells(1,1)**=""Please add a title"",0,RC[-1]*VLOOKUP(R13C1,'Tables (H)'!R2C8:R6C10,2,FALSE))"
```

So in other words I want to use the first cell of the named range to be referenced in my excel formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. After all it's just a string that you construct.

**UNTESTED**

```
Dim sFormula As String

'=IF(A13="Please add a title",0,B17*VLOOKUP(A13,'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE))
sFormula = "=IF(" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(1, 1).Address & _
           "=""Please add a title"",0,B17*VLOOKUP(" & _
           Range(NamedRange).Cells(1, 1).Address & _
           ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE))"

ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula
```

Comment: Looks good but when I try to put it in I get an Compile error: Expected: End of statement.  I think it might be looking for an "End" to the IF... Also get a syntax error, not sure.. this is what I have entered:

ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2,1).Address &" = "Please add a title",0,B16*VLOOKUP(" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2,1).Address &_",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE))

Comment: Can you post the exact formula that you would normally type in Excel cell?

Comment: This is the formula that has been typed into excel, I want the macro to replace the A13's

=IF(A13="Please add a title",0,B17*VLOOKUP(A13,'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE))

Comment: Thank you so much! Life saver, works like a charm.  Although change the ActiveCell.Formula = s to ActiveCell.Formula = sFormula

Answer (score 0):

You can use any VBA function you created in a formula.

Then, create a "function" that does what you intend and call it in your Sheets where needed.